# Edit php.ini in a shared server that prevent this change

Tags: php

I have to configure the PHP installation to have the CURL extension installed and enabled in php.ini by adding the following line: extension = php_curl.dll, but the problem that changing this file is forbidden because the server is shared!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check if you have a .htaccess file instead, some servers give users this so they can make some changes bacause the php.ini file is shared by all users. I think.

Comment: yes, I have .htaccess, so just, I should add this line "extension = php_curl.dll" to the .htaccess?

Comment: I honestly don't know but someone else might ;) Try searching in google etc

Comment: You will have to contact your hosting provider. Since you're not using a dedicated server or vps they will have to install it or modify it for you.

Comment: @user1199434: I find that: Only php.ini settings that are classified as PHP_INI_PERDIR or PHP_INI_ALL can be made this way. But PHP extensions are not settings at all, and cannot be made in .htaccess!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared hosting you have to stick to what they allow you to do so better ask them. If it is forbidden as you say there isn't nothing else to do but asking them.

And most servers are linux servers so I doubt that name of extension that finishes on dll is correct at all.

Besides if the hosting hasn't the extension installed on their system no matter how much you pretend to load it, it won't work. So again, ask hosting for help.